# Sum of the number of prime factors to the power $\alpha$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let for any two reals  $ x $ and  $ y $ such that  $x\leq y $ the quantity $\mathcal{N}_{\alpha}(x,y) $ defined as  $ \sum_{x\leq n\leq y}\Omega(n)^{\alpha} $ where  $\Omega(n) $ is the total number of prime factors of  $ n $ counted with multiplicity. One has  $\lim_{\alpha\to -\infty} \mathcal{N}_{\alpha}(x,y)=\pi(y)-\pi(x) $. Moreover for given  $ x $ and  $ y $ the map  $ \alpha\mapsto\mathcal{N}_{\alpha}(x,y) $ is increasing. I would thus be interested in an asymptotics for both  $ \mathcal{N}_{\alpha}(x,y) $ and it derivative w.r.t  $ \alpha $ in terms of  $ \alpha $ ,  $ x $ and  $ y $.

Has such a function been considered before ?

Answer (score 1):

For $k\in \Bbb N$, let $\pi_k(x)$ be the number of integers $n\le x$ such that $\Omega(n)=k$. Observe that $\pi_1=\pi$. Then
$$
\mathcal{N}_\alpha(2,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_2y\rfloor}2^\alpha\pi_k(y).
$$
For fixed $y$, as $\alpha\to-\infty$, we have
$$
\mathcal{N}_\alpha(2,y)=\pi(y)+2^\alpha\pi_2(y)+O(3^\alpha).
$$
It is not difficult to see that
$$
\pi_2(y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(\sqrt n)}\pi(y/p_k)-\frac12\pi(\sqrt n)\bigl(\pi(\sqrt n)-1\bigr),
$$
here $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime. Asymptotically
$$
\pi_2(y)\sim y\,\frac{\log\log y}{\log y}.
$$

For the general case, consider $\mathcal{N}_\alpha(2,y)-\mathcal{N}_\alpha(2,x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I think the map  $x\mapsto\mathcal{N}_{-x}(2,x) $ should be a good  almost everywhere differentiable approximation of  $ \pi(x) $ for  non integral $ x $.

Comment: Actually one has  $0\leq \tilde{\pi}(x)-\pi(x)\ll\dfrac{x}{\log_{2}(x)^{x}} $ and the last quantity tends to  $ 0 $ as  $ x $ tends to  $ \infty $ while being less than  $ 1 $, where  $ \tilde{\pi}=x\mapsto\mathcal{N}_{-x}(2,x) $ . Hence  $ \pi(x)=\lfloor\tilde{\pi}(x)\rfloor $.

Comment: Read : Actually one has  $0\leq \tilde{\pi}(x)-\pi(x)\ll x.2^{-x}$ and the last quantity tends to  $ 0 $ as  $ x $ tends to  $ \infty $ while being less than  $ 1 $, where  $ \tilde{\pi}=x\mapsto\mathcal{N}_{-x}(2,x) $ . Hence  $ \pi(x)=\lfloor\tilde{\pi}(x)\rfloor $.